# Rsync error with long file name

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I have problem with long file name using rsync (version 3.0.4  protocol version 30) in cygwin (on Windows 8.1)
Rsync give me error: **"some file name" failed: File name too long (91)**

In detail

command:

```
rsync -r -t -v --modify-window=1 --log-file="E:\!SAFE\SYSTEM\SKRIPTE\log_detaljni_wamp.txt" /cygdrive/c/wamp/ /cygdrive/j/Lenovo/C/wamp >> E:\!SAFE\SYSTEM\SKRIPTE\log.txt
```

error:

```
2016/09/20 11:59:34 [9140] rsync: mkstemp "/cygdrive/j/Lenovo/C/wamp/www/wiki/images/thumb/2015-05-22_14_20_42-How_to_fix_the_there_was_a_problem_sending_the_command_to_the_program_Excel_er.png/.120px-2015-05-22_14_20_42-How_to_fix_the_there_was_a_problem_sending_the_command_to_the_program_Excel_er.png.XgcKIu" failed: File name too long (91)
```

Comment: You can't do anything for that... You can try to compress files before get, and decompress after.

Comment: What command are you using?

Comment: Does it happens also if you use `/cygdrive/e` instead on "E:\" ?

Comment: I use E:\ only for log file. I think that is not a problem.

Comment: @Techidiot command that I usig:
**rsync -r -t -v --modify-window=1 --log-file="E:\!SAFE\SYSTEM\SKRIPTE\log_detaljni_wamp.txt" /cygdrive/c/wamp/ /cygdrive/j/Lenovo/C/wamp >> E:\!SAFE\SYSTEM\SKRIPTE\log.txt**

Answer (score 0):

Window has a maximum length for the whole file path.

It's not just an rsync problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2891362 (I believe the "fix" listed on that page is for the Windows Explorer mis-behaviour, not a solution to the underlying limitation).